# Can anyone tell me what this font is or similar?

Tags: font-identification

A client has asked me to create a flyer for them but they don't know their font or have any digital assets to share with me. I've tried using whatfont, but it isn't working on the pdf of the business card they shared with me.

Does anyone know what this font is called, or what might be similar to it?[image: business name font]

Answer (score 6):

[Ruber Stamp Plain](https://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Rubber+Stamp+Plain/) via fontpalace.com

[image: ruberstamp]

Answer (score 2):

same font:

[image]

Rubber Stamp Plain via [Font Palace](https://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Rubber%2BStamp%2BLET%2BPlain/)

[image]

Arial Black for Number